# Need query to select min cost and max date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table and values like this

```
create table minmaxtest
(
id int,
mfg varchar(100),
mfgid varchar(100),
[Desc] varchar(100),
po_date date,
cost money
) 

insert into minmaxtest(id,mfg,mfgid,[Desc],po_date,cost) Values (1,'abc','123','catheter','09/30/15',9)
insert into minmaxtest(id,mfg,mfgid,[Desc],po_date,cost) Values (2,'abc','123','catheter','09/30/15',10)
insert into minmaxtest(id,mfg,mfgid,[Desc],po_date,cost) Values (3,'abc','123','catheter','09/28/15',8)
insert into minmaxtest(id,mfg,mfgid,[Desc],po_date,cost) Values (4,'abc','123','catheter','09/28/15',20)

insert into minmaxtest(id,mfg,mfgid,[Desc],po_date,cost) Values (5,'xyz','666','stent','09/30/15',9)
insert into minmaxtest(id,mfg,mfgid,[Desc],po_date,cost) Values (6,'xyz','666','stent','09/30/15',10)
insert into minmaxtest(id,mfg,mfgid,[Desc],po_date,cost) Values (7,'xyz','666','stent','09/28/15',8)
insert into minmaxtest(id,mfg,mfgid,[Desc],po_date,cost) Values (8,'xyz','666','stent','09/28/15',20)
```

I need to get the max po_date and min cost as shown in the figure [image]

i tried like this but not getting proper value , Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**My code :**

```
*select * from minmaxtest where po_date in(select max(po_date) from minmaxtest)
and cost in (select min(cost) from minmaxtest)*
```

Comment: What is the logic behind getting your desired result?

Comment: Also, your expected results aren't representative of your sample data. Where is `'pencil'` or `'book`' in your Sample data?

Comment: I don't understand the expected output, in particular from where are those `iD` values are coming.

Comment: observe po_date and cost

Comment: Output should have min cost and max po_date

Comment: sorry ignore pencil or book data

Comment: If we ignore the data containing `'pencil'` and `'book'` we have no expected result set. We need both Sample data and representative Expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
;with cte
as
(
SELECT 
    SequenceId = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY mfg ORDER BY id),
    id,
    mfg,
    mfgid,
    [Desc],
    po_date = MAX(PO_Date) OVER(PARTITION BY mfgid),     
    cost = MIN(cost) OVER(PARTITION BY mfgid,po_date)
FROM minmaxtest
)
select
    *
    from cte
       where SequenceId = 1
```

My Result

[image]

Comment: min cost must be 9, because after  grouping po_date as well as cost, it will be 9

Answer (score 0):

`;with cte
as
(
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by mfg ORDER BY po_date desc, cost asc) as RN,
    id,
    mfg,
    mfgid,
    [Desc],
    po_date ,

    cost 
FROM minmaxtest
)
select
    id,
    mfg as Productmanufacturer,
    mfgid,
    [Desc] as ProductDescription,
    po_date ,

    cost 
    from cte
       where RN = 1`

Output:

[image]